# Google Reports API activities.list gives ipAddress: 0.1.0.40

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client

While retrieving audit events from activities.list() in Google Apps Admin SDK, some activities have their ipAddress field as 0.1.0.40 and 0.1.0.0. In what cases could this be the source IP address, since they seem to be private or restricted IP addresses?

```
 {
  "kind": "admin#reports#activities",
  "etag": "\"6KGrH_UY2JDZNpgjPKUOF8yJF1A/l6ZMtXXRXWtSeG8M3t2g4k5pUaY\"",
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "admin#reports#activity",
      "id": {
        "time": "2016-12-28T11:23:26.269Z",
        "uniqueQualifier": "2877532833757184598",
        "applicationName": "drive",
        "customerId": "C01c818ge"
      },
       "etag": "\"6KGrH_UY2JDZNpgjPKUOF8yJF1A/7lASgpMTSWwMHfLg8I4-s07wD_Q\"",
      "actor": {
        "email": "def@abc.com",
        "profileId": "115227377397945077346"
      },
      "ipAddress": "0.1.0.40",
      "events": [
        {
          "type": "access",
          "name": "create",
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "primary_event",
              "boolValue": true
            },
            {
              "name": "owner",
              "value": "def@abc.com"
            },
            {
              "name": "doc_id",
              "value": "0ByoIcq_NoMgZDY19wc2RnZE0"
            },
            {
              "name": "doc_type",
              "value": "unknown"
            },
            {
              "name": "doc_title",
              "value": "Untitled"
            },
            {
              "name": "owner_is_team_drive",
              "boolValue": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-admin#example_response), it is stated here that the `"ipAddress"` properties contains the user's IP address. And from this [Activities: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list#response), it contains  IP address of the user doing the action. This is the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the user when logging into G Suite which may or may not reflect the user's physical location. For example, the IP address can be the user's proxy server's address or a virtual private network (VPN) address. The API supports IPv4 and IPv6.